# How to pull the number of customers that have signed up and registered

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, database, customer-account

I am looking to pull the customer's actual data who have manually signed up and registered on website.

In admin when i clicked on the menu item **customers > manage customers**,

it gives me a number that seems like a lot. I believe this is the customer data of everyone who's ever purchased anything, including guests.

I would like to know the number of just registered accounts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@thismethod, The answer is in your question description only.

You already told that,

> In admin when i click on the menu item CUSTOMERS > MANAGE CUSTOMERS it gives me a number that seems like a lot. I believe this is the customer data of everyone who's ever purchased anything

**Manage customers** grid only shows you the registered customers on your website. You can find the number of registered users from here.

No guest customers data is there.